# Install Xcode command line tools, command line

Tags: osx, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on a server via SSH, but f.e. `brew install wget` yields

> fatal: HTTP request failed Error: Your Command Line Tools are too
>   outdated.

I need to update my Command Line Tools via the command line. I've seen elsewhere that I should use `xcode-select --install` however on the server this just prints the documentation for `xcode-select`. `--install` is not listed among the available flags. Old version of `xcode-select`? How to fix?

The operating system, according `uname`, is "Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0."

Comment: Is Xcode installed on the machine?  I think that's required for `xcode-select --install` to work.  Also, I'm pretty sure that opens a GUI dialog to handle the actual installation process.  Can you VNC into the machine?

Comment: @DopeGhoti It's installed, `xcode-select -version` tells me that I have version `2343` installed. That version just doesn't seem to accept the `--install` flag unfortunately. I don't know if I can use a GUI somehow, I would really prefer to do this via the command line.

Comment: 10.4.0? Tiger *without* any updates? It is from 2005, and it is unsupported since 2009. What machine is that, XServe or a Mini Mac powerpc? NetBSD comes to mind, no idea if there is still support for Linux for that kind of machines.